# Cumulative Binomial Probability C#

Tags: c#, math

I'm trying to calculate the cumulative binomial probability of 'n' trials, with 'p' probability and 'r' as the successful outcome of each trial. I have written the following code that works sometimes, but not always:

```
Console.WriteLine ();
Console.WriteLine ("B~(n, p)");

incorrectN:

Console.WriteLine ("Enter value of 'n': ");
int n = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());

if (n < 0) {
    Console.WriteLine ("ERROR: 'n' must be greater than 0");
    goto incorrectN;
}

incorrectP:

Console.WriteLine ();
Console.WriteLine ("Enter value of 'p': "); 
double p = Convert.ToDouble (Console.ReadLine ());

if (p > 1) {
    Console.WriteLine ();
    Console.WriteLine ("ERROR: 'p' must be between 0 and 1");
    goto incorrectP;
}

Console.WriteLine ();

incorrectS:

int r = GetR();
int k = r;

double binomTotal = 0;

for (int j = r + 1; j > 0; j--) {

  int nCr = Factorial(n) / (Factorial(n - (r - k)) * Factorial(r - k));

  binomTotal = binomTotal + nCr * Math.Pow(p, (r - k)) * Math.Pow(1 - p, (n - (r - k)));

  k--;
}

Console.WriteLine();
Console.WriteLine(binomTotal);
```

P.S. I have written the `GetR()` and `Factorial()` functions elsewhere within the class, where `GetR()` asks the user for the value of 'r' and `Factorial()` is defined as follows:

```
public static int Factorial(int x)
{
    return x <= 1 ? 1 : x * Factorial(x - 1);
}
```

I tested the code with values `n = 10, p = 0.5` and `r = 5` and the output is `0.623046875`, which is correct. However, when I use `n = 13, p = 0.35` and `r = 7`, I get `0.297403640622647` instead of `0.9538`.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Where does `n` come from? Please post actual, tested and compiling code.

Comment: No related but ... don't use goto or the .Net evil will eat your soul on an infinite agony ... :)

Comment: `Factorial(13) = 6227020800` > `Int32.MaxValue = 2147483647` :) Change the return type of the factorial method to long.

Comment: It'd make sense to use `double` for factorials here, since the answer needn't be exact.

Comment: Would help if you gave links to some definitions as well, and maybe a brief explanation of what is possible to explain in plain English as well

Comment: Using double for Factorial() works. Thanks everyone! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to your own answer:

```
public static double Factorial(double x)
{
    return x <= 1 ? 1 : x * Factorial(x - 1);
}
```

accepts a `double` parameter, which means that `x` is not restricted to be an integer. 
So you could call your `Factorial` method like this.

```
var fac1 = Factorial(1.4);
var fac2 = Factorial(2.7);
```

However, this does not make sense since the factorial [image: n!] is defined only* for [image: n], meaning that 
[image: 1.7!] is undefined.

So, instead of using `double` and allowing for invalid inputs, you should be using [`long`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/long) instead, which has a greater range than `int`.

```
public static long Factorial(long x)
{
    return x <= 1 ? 1 : x * Factorial(x - 1);
}
```

---

<sub>* there are some cases where factorials can be used with real values as well - e.g. by using the gamma function - but I don't think they're relevant to your use case and therefore you should not allow invalid parameters.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
public static int Factorial(int x)
    {
        return x <= 1 ? 1 : x * Factorial(x - 1);
    }
```

To:

```
public static double Factorial(double x)
    {
        return x <= 1 ? 1 : x * Factorial(x - 1);
    }
```

Because `Factorial(13)` is too large for Int32.